# Confusion Matrix

Tags: tables

I am busy with creating a confusion matrix table where I also add the original total in the column Actual.

How can I make my table look like this (The column actual and total can be removed in my tables (i want this look))?

(Without the green and red colors)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\cline{3-5}
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Predicted}} &  \\ \cline{3-5} 
 &  & \textbf{default} & \textbf{non-default} & \textbf{Actual} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{References}} & \textbf{default} & 31300 & 6774 & 38074 \\ \cline{2-2}
 & \textbf{non-default} & 4053 & 72101 & 76154 \\ \hline
 & \textbf{Total} & 35353 & 78875 & 114228 \\ \cline{2-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you think needs to be improved?

Comment: @AndréC Thank you for the suggestion I edited my question

Comment: Any table you would like to make coul be easily  done using https://www.tablesgenerator.com. In the same way, for the math equations I recommend you to use https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php. 
Changing the text color is as simple as use \textcolor{blue}{This is a sample text in blue.} with \usepackage{xcolor}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you a foundation from which you can start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{|c} | }
  \cline{3-4}
  \mc{} & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Condition Phase (worst case)} & \mc{} \\
  \cline{3-4}
  \mc{} & & \makecell{Condition \\ Positive/ \\ Shaded} & 
    \makecell{Condition \\ Negative/ \\ Unshaded} & \mc{\textbf{Actual}} \\
  \hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{\makecell{Testing \\ Phase \\ (best case)}} & 
    \makecell{Test \\ Positive/ \\ Shaded} & 
    \makecell{True positive \\ shaded \\ $T_p$ \\ \textit{(Correct)}} & 
    \makecell{False positive \\ shaded \\ $F_p$ \\ \textit{(Incorrect)}} &
    \makecell{Precision/Positive \\ Predictive Value \\ (PPV) \\ $\frac{T_p}{T_p + F_p} \times 100\%$} \\
  \cline{2-5}
  & 
    \makecell{Test \\ Negative/ \\ Unshaded} & 
    \makecell{False negative \\ unshaded \\ $F_n$ \\ \textit{(Incorrect)}} &
    \makecell{True negative \\ unshaded \\ $T_n$ \\ \textit{(Correct)}} &
    \makecell{Negative \\ Predictive Value \\ (NPV) \\ $\frac{T_n}{T_n + F_n} \times 100\%$} \\
  \hline
  \mc{} & & \makecell{Sensitivity/Recall \\ Rate (RR) \\ $\frac{T_p}{T_p + F_n} \times 100\%$} &
    \makecell{Specificity Rate \\ (SR) \\ $\frac{T_n}{T_n + F_p} \times 100\%$} & \mc{} \\
  \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```